# Printing Qt data structures (QList, QString, etc.) in XCode 3.xx GDB

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, gdb, qlist

I am trying to debug some Qt containers in XCode and the results I get back from GDB are not useful:

```
    print l1
$1 = (QSharedPointer<QList<SNAPSHOT> > &) @0x102780650: {
  <QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount<QList<SNAPSHOT> >> = {
    <QtSharedPointer::Basic<QList<SNAPSHOT> >> = {
      value = 0x1161e47e0
    }, 
    members of QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount<QList<SNAPSHOT> >: 
    d = 0x1161ace00
  }, <No data fields>}
Current language:  auto; currently c++
(gdb) print strQuery
$2 = {
  d = 0x1161e2890
```

How do I get some useful out put from l1 (QList) and strQuery (QString)?
I've already tried using this .gdbinit which adds some macros like "printq4string" but those are quite painful to use as when printing out structs i need to manually run this on each member variable.

Comment: How did you debug these variables? Is this a terminal output of GDB after some statement in your code? Do you know the `qDebug() << ...` method?

Comment: I use print in GDB, yes I know qDebug(), but its compile time and completely unscalable as the sole debugging tool.  I use it over std::cerr but its qDebug() overall is more limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the source and came up with this suboptimal approach, I leave it to the community to improve on this:

```
    QString s1("This should be easy");

    QList<QString> s;
    s.push_back("Can you debug me?");

(gdb) print/c s1.d.data[0]@30
$2 = {84 'T', 104 'h', 105 'i', 115 's', 32 ' ', 115 's', 104 'h', 111 'o', 117 'u', 108 'l', 100 'd', 32 ' ', 98 'b', 101 'e', 32 ' ', 101 'e', 97 'a', 115 's', 121 'y', 0 '\0', 0 '\0', 0 '\0', 0 '\0', 0 '\0', 0 '\0', 0 '\0', 0 '\0', 14 '\016', 0 '\0', 0 '\0'}

(gdb) print/c ((QString*)s.d.array).d.data[0]@20
$12 = {67 'C', 97 'a', 110 'n', 32 ' ', 121 'y', 111 'o', 117 'u', 32 ' ', 100 'd', 101 'e', 98 'b', 117 'u', 103 'g', 32 ' ', 109 'm', 101 'e', 63 '?', 0 '\0', 0 '\0', 0 '\0'}
```

Comment: how do you manage to get this data object from s1.d ? all I get is no member named 'data' in 'QListData::Data' ? This is killing me

Comment: Just a side note: in Qt 5.12 it is `print/c *xxx.d[0].data()@20`

Answer (score 4):

For strings, `p my_string.toStdString().c_str()` works

```
(gdb) p my_string.toStdString().c_str()
$5 = 0x55556d10d7d0 "abc 123 test string"
```

Comment: Well, you have my upvote even though it didn't work for me because one of those funcs are inlined in my current program.  Unfortunately, that can even happen in an -O0 build with gcc's `__attribute__((always_inline))`.  But this is, by far, the simplest answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok this drove me nuts but I got it.

First make sure your project is set to compile with GCC 4.2 and not pure LLVM as shown in :
 [image]

LLVM is now set as the default compiler in XCode 4 and it doesn't add correct debugging information for struct inside classes.

Now in your ~/.gdbinit just add :

```
define pqts
    printf "(QString)0x%x (length=%i): \"",&$arg0,$arg0.d->size
    set $i=0
    while $i < $arg0.d->size
        set $c=$arg0.d->data[$i++]
        if $c < 32 || $c > 127
                printf "\\u0x%04x", $c
        else
                printf "%c", (char)$c
        end
    end
    printf "\"\n"
end
```

and you can now simply type `pqts s1` and it will dump your `QString` nicely.

Comment: I have gotten Qstrings working, but I want to it to work for all native types now, qMaps, qLists, and also when I print out a qlist I want it to be recursive and smart enough to understand the strings

Comment: Note: `data` is a method, so you need to replace `data` with `data()`.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `p *varName.shd` which dumps it as a QShared with the string data inside, but I'm not sure if that'll work for QList, definitely does for QString.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I simply add this function for strings to my utilities:

```
char* q(const QString& string)
{
    return(string.toUtf8().data());
}
```

Then, `p q(myString)` works.